# OpenVPN is working but not DNS resolution

Tags: debian, dns, openvpn

I am using :

```
uname -a 
Linux 2.6.32-042stab108.5 #1 SMP Wed Jun 17 20:20:17 MSK 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is my server config:

```
cat /etc/openvpn/server.conf | egrep -v "#|;"
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server_openvpn_certificate.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 127.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.11"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
```

This is the client config:

```
cat /etc/openvpn/client.conf | egrep -v "#|;"
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote *.*.*.* 1194 #I've put server IP there.
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/my.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/my.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

This are some logs I got after starting Openvpn (note the connected client at the end):

```
openvpn /etc/openvpn/server.conf 
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556076 Current Parameter Settings:
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556159   config = '/etc/openvpn/server.conf'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556173   mode = 1
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556186   persist_config = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556203   persist_mode = 1
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556216   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556227   show_digests = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556238   show_engines = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556248   genkey = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556259   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556271   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556286 Connection profiles [default]:
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556297   proto = udp
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556336   local = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556349   local_port = 1194
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556360   remote = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556371   remote_port = 1194
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556382   remote_float = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556398   bind_defined = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556409   bind_local = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556420   connect_retry_seconds = 5
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556432   connect_timeout = 10
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556445   connect_retry_max = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556457   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556469   socks_proxy_port = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556480   socks_proxy_retry = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556491   tun_mtu = 1500
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556502   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556514   link_mtu = 1500
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556525   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556536   tun_mtu_extra = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556547   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556558   mtu_discover_type = -1
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556570   fragment = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556582   mssfix = 1450
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556593   explicit_exit_notification = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556604 Connection profiles END
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556616   remote_random = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556628   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556639   dev = 'tun'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556650   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556661   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556673   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556684   topology = 1
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556695   tun_ipv6 = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556706   ifconfig_local = '10.8.0.1'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556718   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '10.8.0.2'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556729   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556740   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556751   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556762   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556774   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556785   shaper = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556795   mtu_test = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556806   mlock = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556817   keepalive_ping = 10
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556829   keepalive_timeout = 120
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556840   inactivity_timeout = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556850   ping_send_timeout = 10
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556862   ping_rec_timeout = 240
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556873   ping_rec_timeout_action = 2
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556884   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556895   remap_sigusr1 = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556906   persist_tun = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556917   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556928   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556939   persist_key = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556949   passtos = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556961   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556972   username = 'nobody'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556982   groupname = 'nogroup'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=556993   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557004   cd_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557015   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557025   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557036   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557047   down_pre = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557058   up_restart = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557068   up_delay = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557079   daemon = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557090   inetd = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557101   log = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557112   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557123   nice = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557134   verbosity = 6
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557145   mute = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557155   gremlin = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557166   status_file = 'openvpn-status.log'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557178   status_file_version = 1
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557193   status_file_update_freq = 60
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557205   occ = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557217   rcvbuf = 65536
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557228   sndbuf = 65536
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557239   mark = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557249   sockflags = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557260   fast_io = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557272   lzo = 7
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557282   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557293   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557304   route_default_metric = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557379   route_noexec = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557391   route_delay = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557402   route_delay_window = 30
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557413   route_delay_defined = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557424   route_nopull = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557435   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557446   max_routes = 100
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557457   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557474   route 10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0/nil/nil
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557485   management_addr = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557496   management_port = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557507   management_user_pass = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557519   management_log_history_cache = 250
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557530   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557542   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557556   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557567   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557579   management_flags = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557595   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557607   key_direction = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557619   ciphername_defined = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557630   ciphername = 'BF-CBC'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557641   authname_defined = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557703   authname = 'SHA1'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557719   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557730   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557741   keysize = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557752   engine = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557767   replay = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557778   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557861   replay_window = 64
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557956   replay_time = 15
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557968   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557979   use_iv = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=557991   test_crypto = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558002   tls_server = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558015   tls_client = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558026   key_method = 2
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558038   ca_file = '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558050   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558061   dh_file = '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558072   cert_file = '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server_openvpn_certificate.crt'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558085   priv_key_file = '/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server_openvpn_certificate.key'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558097   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558108   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558119   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558130   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558141   verify_x509_type = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558152   verify_x509_name = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558163   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558175   ns_cert_type = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558190   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558203   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558215   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558226   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558237   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558248   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558258   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558400   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558412   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558510   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558527   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558538   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558549   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558559   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558570   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558581   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558592   remote_cert_eku = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558602   ssl_flags = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558613   tls_timeout = 2
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558624   renegotiate_bytes = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558635   renegotiate_packets = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558646   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558656   handshake_window = 60
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558668   transition_window = 3600
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558681   single_session = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558692   push_peer_info = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558703   tls_exit = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558714   tls_auth_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558725   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558737   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558748   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558760   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558772   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558783   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558794   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558805   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558816   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558827   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558838   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558850   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558860   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558877   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558889   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558900   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558973   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=558991   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559003   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559014   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559026   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559037   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559048   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559059   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559070   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559080   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559091   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559102   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559113   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559123   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559135   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559146   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559158   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559171   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559182   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559196   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559209   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559221   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559233   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559244   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559255   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559266   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559278   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559288   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559300   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559339   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559351   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559363   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559374   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559386   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559397   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559410   server_network = 10.8.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559423   server_netmask = 255.255.255.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559436   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559496   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559509   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559521   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559533   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559545   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559556   push_entry = 'redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559567   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 127.0.0.1'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559579   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.11'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559590   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559603   push_entry = 'route 10.8.0.1'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559614   push_entry = 'topology net30'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559625   push_entry = 'ping 10'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559636   push_entry = 'ping-restart 120'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559646   ifconfig_pool_defined = ENABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559658   ifconfig_pool_start = 10.8.0.4
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559670   ifconfig_pool_end = 10.8.0.251
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559682   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559693   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = 'ipp.txt'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559705   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559716   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559727   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559738   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559750   n_bcast_buf = 256
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559760   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559771   real_hash_size = 256
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559782   virtual_hash_size = 256
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559792   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559803   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559814   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559825   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559836   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559847   tmp_dir = '/tmp'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559858   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559870   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559882   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559893   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559905   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559917   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559927   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559938   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559949   cf_max = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559959   cf_per = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559970   max_clients = 1024
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559981   max_routes_per_client = 256
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=559992   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560003   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560014   port_share_host = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560025   port_share_port = 0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560035   client = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560046   pull = DISABLED
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560056   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560069 OpenVPN 2.3.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=560093 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, LZO 2.08
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=569504 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=570362 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=570401 Socket Buffers: R=[133120->131072] S=[133120->131072]
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=570849 ROUTE_GATEWAY ON_LINK IFACE=venet0 HWADDR=00:00:00:00:00:00
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=571278 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=571304 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=571470 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=572164 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=588878 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.1 peer 10.8.0.2
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=591366 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=593458 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594254 GID set to nogroup
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594283 UID set to nobody
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594344 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594357 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594386 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594465 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594515 ifconfig_pool_read(), in='myHost,10.8.0.4', TODO: IPv6
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594531 succeeded -> ifconfig_pool_set()
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594544 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594556 myHost,10.8.0.4
Tue Aug 11 17:16:56 2015 us=594597 Initialization Sequence Completed
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445356 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445470 87.231.96.37:40861 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445550 87.231.96.37:40861 LZO compression initialized
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445788 87.231.96.37:40861 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445809 87.231.96.37:40861 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445858 87.231.96.37:40861 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445872 87.231.96.37:40861 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445922 87.231.96.37:40861 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=445945 87.231.96.37:40861 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=446007 87.231.96.37:40861 UDPv4 READ [14] from [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=446042 87.231.96.37:40861 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861, sid=a32d8e15 e3a80243
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=446097 87.231.96.37:40861 UDPv4 WRITE [26] to [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=538563 87.231.96.37:40861 UDPv4 READ [22] from [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 0 ]
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=542690 87.231.96.37:40861 UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=1 DATA len=100
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=542830 87.231.96.37:40861 UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 1 ]
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=546812 87.231.96.37:40861 UDPv4 READ [114] from [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861: P_CONTROL_V1 kid=0 [ ] pid=2 DATA len=100
Tue Aug 11 17:17:00 2015 us=546934 87.231.96.37:40861 UDPv4 WRITE [22] to [AF_INET]87.231.96.37:40861: P_ACK_V1 kid=0 [ 2 ]
```

The server resolv.conf:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search mydomain.com
domain mydomain.com
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.11
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

IP Forward:

```
cat  /etc/sysctl.conf|grep -v "#"
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I tried also :

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

The server NAT rules:

```
     iptables -t nat -L
    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    SNAT       all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere             to:167.114.2.27
    SNAT       all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere             to:167.114.2.27
    MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            
    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere            

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
```

Firewall rules:

(The body of the message is limited to 30000 characters, so please find it here : http://pastebin.com/j7r6yTBN )

This is OpenVpn client logs (don't mind about the IP address of the vpn) :

```
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/client.conf 
Tue Aug 11 23:29:33 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Tue Aug 11 23:29:33 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->131072] S=[212992->131072]
Tue Aug 11 23:29:33 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Tue Aug 11 23:29:33 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:1194
Tue Aug 11 23:29:34 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:1194, sid=bdf2bcf1 928efbf8
Tue Aug 11 23:29:35 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=Fort-Funston, OU=MyOrganizationalUnit, CN=Fort-Funston CA, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
Tue Aug 11 23:29:35 2015 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Tue Aug 11 23:29:35 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=SanFrancisco, O=Fort-Funston, OU=MyOrganizationalUnit, CN=myServerTun, name=EasyRSA, emailAddress=me@myhost.mydomain
Tue Aug 11 23:29:37 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Aug 11 23:29:37 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 11 23:29:37 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Aug 11 23:29:37 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Aug 11 23:29:37 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Tue Aug 11 23:29:37 2015 [myServerTun] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]*.*.*.*:1194
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 SENT CONTROL [myServerTun]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 127.0.0.1,dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.11,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.8.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=80:19:34:4b:47:54
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 /sbin/ip route add *.*.*.*/32 via 192.168.0.1
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
Tue Aug 11 23:29:39 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

On the client:

```
 nslookup yahoo.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

On the server I have fail2ban installed and :

```
cat /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/openvpn.conf
[Definition]
failregex = <HOST>:\\d{1,5} TLS Auth Error
    <HOST>:\\d{1,5} VERIFY ERROR:
    <HOST>:\\d{1,5} TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

And [this](http://pastebin.com/Yp0iF4KB) is a tcpdump on server side.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Probably you don't actually have Internet connectivity through the VPN. Can you ping an IP address (e.g., 8.8.4.4?). Is IP forwarding enabled on the server?

Comment: ... also, pushing a DNS server of 127.0.0.1 is probably not what you want (but it should just fall back to the others). If you want the VPN server to be used for DNS, you need to push one of its IPs, not the magic 127/8 localhost network. (10.8.0.1 might work, don't recall if that does with --server).

Comment: 100% packets loss. So there is no Internet connectivity ! But I have already IP forward on systcl file : net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Comment: Try pinging the server over the VPN. Make sure that works. Also, what's up with your NAT rules? It looks like you have duplicate rules and also are trying both SNAT and MASQUERADE... (And also disclosed your public IP address there.)

Comment: pinging the server with its pub IP is working.

Comment: Pinging the public IP (remote VPN endpoint IP) doesn't go over the VPN. You need to ping one of its other IPs.

Comment: other IPs, if you mean 10.8.0.1 it does'nt work also on ping.

Comment: Check your firewall config to see if its blocking the packet (`iptables -t filter -vL`). Also you can try tcpdump on the VPN device to see if the traffic is getting through at all. Also, is your kernel new enough to have `net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding`? If so, make sure that is 1. (Well, or you can do it per-interface as well).

Comment: Please check the updates on the message :-)

Comment: Did you try tcpdump?

Comment: I just added the output on the message :-)

Comment: One should not care about DNS prior to fixing network connectivity problems.